# read R.string from context in AsyncTask

Tags: java, android

I am new to Java, but not to programming, however can anyone help to explain why I have following crashes when dealing with reading of R.string from AsyncTask?

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
```

I have a class with AsyncTask:

```
public class getBitmapFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>{

    ImageView bmImage;
    private Context mContext;

    public getBitmapFromURL( Context context, ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
        mContext = context;
    }
```

within doInBackground method:

```
protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {

try {
            savebitmap( mIcon11, target_file[1]);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

and the file saving method itself:

```
private File savebitmap(Bitmap bmp, String file_name) throws IOException {

//**** --- >>> This line causes the crash:
String app_name = mContext.getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.app_name);



    Log.e( "APP_NAME INFO:", app_name);
                File app_dest_folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory () + "/" + app_name );
                if(!app_dest_folder.exists()){
                    app_dest_folder.mkdir();
...
```

calling AsyncTask is done from GetContent class:

```
public class GetContent extends AppCompatActivity {

private Context context;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_get_content);
    loadimages();
}

    public void loadimages() {
new getBitmapFromURL(context, (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.wc_latest_iv)).execute(url);
}

...
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: how you are calling getBitmapFromURL class

Comment: added the getBitmapFromURL class and asynctask.execute()

Comment: post your `asynctask.execute()` statement.. @ondej

Comment: have updated the answer please check and update if it works.. @ondej

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to execute asynctask class

```
   new getBitmapFromURL(GetContent.this, (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.wc_latest_iv)).execute(url);
```

> this is because you havent initialized the `context` ..

Comment: Many thanks, works! Got it. Very fast and effective answer on this site as usually :)